# CSS Multiple Class Hover On Button Effects & Transitioning

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, elementor

I have a button that has an icon and I'm trying to achieve a hover effect, I got the hover effect to work but it only works when I hover over the icon and not the text of the button.

When I move my cursor away from the icon the hover effect stops but it is not smooth, the effect stops instantly.

Hope someone can help me:

1. Smooth hover stop animation on the padding
2. Make icon grow on hover of button text.

Platform: WordPress + Elementor

[image]

My CSS

```
.button-blue .fa-long-arrow-alt-right:before {
content: "\f30b";
background-color: #31A0F8;
color: #fff;
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 30px;
}

.button-blue, .fa-long-arrow-alt-right:hover:before {
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 30px;
transform: scale(1);
transition: 0.15s all ease;
}

.button-blue, .fa-long-arrow-alt-right:hover:after {
transform: scale(1);
transition: 0.15s all ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the property `transition` to the base-selector without `:hover`

```css
.button-blue .fa-long-arrow-alt-right:before {
  content: "\f30b";
  background-color: #31A0F8;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 0.15s all ease;
}

.button-blue, .fa-long-arrow-alt-right:after {
  transition: 0.15s all ease;
}

.button-blue, .fa-long-arrow-alt-right:hover:before {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.button-blue, .fa-long-arrow-alt-right:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the transition for the hover is now working perfectly. The only problem now is that the hover effect is only playing when I hover over the icon and not the text. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?